# Linked list traversing with and without the next field

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes, traversal

I have written two functions while learning Linked list. First counts and returns number of nodes in the list. Second adds new node towards the end of the list. Can you please help me understand why I need to use "current->next" to check for NULL in my code below in the addatend function? I did not have to use it for first function. Without that my exe crashes with bad pointer...

Thank you very much for your time and help.

```
int length(node * head) {
    node * current = head;
    int count = 0;

    while(current != NULL){  // This line works as expected....
        count ++;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return count;
}

void addatend (node * head, int value){
    node * newnode = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node * current = head;

    while (current != NULL){   // This line would not work?? If I use current->next != NULL it works.....
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = newnode;
    newnode->data = value;
    newnode->next = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the second function your are accessing `current->MEMBER` after you changed it to `current->next`, while in the first one you are not. That is, in the first one you just run to end, and end up with a `NULL` pointer, but you don't use it, so it's ok. In the second one, you do use it.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for prompt response. Sorry I am not following. When you say accessing the member, are you referring to 3 assignment statements? Even in the second function I am not accessing member UNTIL I reach the end and exit the while loop. I am wondering why I cannot reach up to the last element the same way and then assign whatever value required... Pardon my slow learning please!

Comment: When you "reach the end", you can't use `current` anymore, because now it is NULL. In the first function, it is ok, because you don't use it. In the second you need to use it, so you have to make the change an test `current->next` instead of `current`.

Comment: Ah! Understood! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

In order not to mess up with your original linked-list you copy the head to the current, and then you can do what you want with that current node.
Linked lists are generated like:

```
typedef struct e
{
   int data;
   struct e *next;
} node;
```

which means each node (in my example) has a data of type integer and a pointer to the next node. Let's suppose that our list has 4 objects:

```
 1->2->3->4->NULL
```

the first node (data=1) point to its next node (data=2) and so on till last node (data=4) which the next node does not exist so will point to NULL.

in the function "addatend" in order to add new node to the end of the linked-list you should travel through the last element of the list (data=4 in my example), which the node next to it will point to NULL, so you should go through the list till the end and when you arrive there, you can add the "newnode".